# Max recursion error python poker game

Tags: python, recursion

I am making a simple poker game in python. When performing the betting round i get a max recursion depth error and I'm not too sure on how I would fix it. I've had this problem before with a previous version of the code, but I've now split the betting round into two halves (one for Human and one for Ai). I've tried all the fixes I could think of and on stack overflow and still no use.

Here is the code:

```
def bettingRoundHuman():
    print "Human, your cards are: " + str(human.card1) + ", " + str(human.card2)
    action = raw_input("What is your move? (r/c/f): ")
    if action == 'f':
        ai.score = ai.score + 1
        Table.winner = "Ai"
        bettingRound().won = True
        return True
    elif action == 'r':
        raiseAmount = input("Raise by: ")
        if bettingRoundHuman().action == 'r':
            human.money = human.money - bettingRoundAi().raiseAmount - raiseAmount
            Table.pot = Table.pot +  bettingRoundAi().raiseAmount + raiseAmount
            bettingRound().won = False
            return False
        elif bettingRoundHuman().action == 'c':
            human.money = human.money - raiseAmount 
            Table.pot = Table.pot + raiseAmount
            bettingRound().won = False
            return False
        else:
            human.money = human.money - raiseAmount 
            Table.pot = Table.pot + raiseAmount
            bettingRound().won = False
            return False
    elif action == 'c':
        if bettingRoundAi().action == 'c':
            bettingRound().won = False
            return True
        elif bettingRoundAi().action ==  'r':
            human.money = human.money -  bettingRoundAi().raiseAmount
            Table.pot = Table.pot +  bettingRoundAi().raiseAmount
            bettingRound().won = False
            return False
        else: 
            bettingRound().won = False
            return False

def bettingRoundAi():
    print "Ai, your cards are: " + str(ai.card1) + ", " + str(ai.card2)
    action = raw_input("What is your move? (r/c/f): ")
    if action == 'f':
        human.score = human.score + 1
        Table.winner = 'Human'
        bettingRound().won = True
        return True
    elif action == 'r':
        raiseAmount = input("Raise by: ")
        if bettingRoundHuman().action == 'r':
            ai.money = ai.money - bettingRoundHuman().raiseAmount - raiseAmount
            Table.pot = Table.pot +  bettingRoundHuman().raiseAmount + raiseAmount
            bettingRound().won = False
            return False
        elif bettingRoundHuman().action == 'c':
            ai.money = ai.money - raiseAmount 
            Table.pot = Table.pot + raiseAmount
            bettingRound().won = False
            return False
    elif action == 'c':
        if bettingRoundHuman().action ==  'r':
            ai.money = ai.money -  bettingRoundHuman().raiseAmount
            Table.pot = Table.pot +  bettingRoundHuman().raiseAmount
            bettingRound().won = False
            return False
        elif bettingRoundHuman().action == 'c':
            bettingRound().won = False
            return True
        else: 
            bettingRound().won = False
            return False

def playGame():
    startPlayer = bettingRoundOrder()
    human.money = human.money - Table.entrymoney
    ai.money = ai.money - Table.entrymoney
    Table.pot = (Table.pot + 2*Table.entrymoney)

    if bettingRound() == False:
        print "The table's cards are: " + str(Table.flop1) + ", " + str(Table.flop2) + ", " + str(Table.flop3)
        if bettingRound() == False:
            print "The table's cards are: " + str(Table.flop1) + ", " + str(Table.flop2) + ", " + str(Table.flop3) + ", " + str(Table.turn)
            if bettingRound() == False:
                print "The table's cards are: " + str(Table.flop1) + ", " + str(Table.flop2) + ", " + str(Table.flop3) + ", " + str(Table.turn) + ", " + str(Table.river)
                if bettingRound() == False:
                    return cardCompare()
    else: return Table.winner

def bettingRoundOrder():
    if randint(0,100) >= 50: 
        return 1
    else:
        return 2

def bettingRound():
    won = False
    if playGame().startPlayer == 1:
        while flag == False:
            finishH = bettingRoundHuman()
            finishA = bettingRoundAi()
            if finishH == True or finishA == True:
                flag = True
            else: flag = False
    elif playGame().startPlayer == 2:
        while flag == False:
            finishA = bettingRoundAi()
            finishH = bettingRoundHuman()
            if finishH == True or finishA == True:
                flag = True
            else: flag = flase
    if won == True: return True
    else: return False
```

Full code here: http://pastebin.com/sdfwWjsg

Here's the last working version: http:// pastebin.com/35gapWNi

And here is the error code I'm getting:

```
[Keeps repeating and too long to put in question]
  File "/home/laurence/Documents/poker (test).py", line 180, in bettingRound
    if playGame().startPlayer == 1:
  File "/home/laurence/Documents/poker (test).py", line 162, in playGame
    if bettingRound() == False:
  File "/home/laurence/Documents/poker (test).py", line 180, in bettingRound
    if playGame().startPlayer == 1:
  File "/home/laurence/Documents/poker (test).py", line 162, in playGame
    if bettingRound() == False:
  File "/home/laurence/Documents/poker (test).py", line 180, in bettingRound
    if playGame().startPlayer == 1:
  File "/home/laurence/Documents/poker (test).py", line 157, in playGame
    startPlayer = bettingRoundOrder()
  File "/home/laurence/Documents/poker (test).py", line 173, in bettingRoundOrder
    if randint(0,100) >= 50: 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 242, in randint
    return self.randrange(a, b+1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 185, in randrange
    istart = _int(start)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Full error code here: http://pastebin.com/52CH0AvL

I'm thinking its something to do with the code not breaking out of a loop when it should do but I can't find anywhere where it's not.

Comment: Please share full exception output

Comment: Please don't make it that difficult for us to help you: The first error I get with your code is `NameError: global name 'randint' is not defined`. After adding `from random import randint` the code runs but nothing happens. After adding `playGame()` at the end I get the error `NameError: global name 'human' is not defined`. Can you provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which can be copied and pasted and shows your error, please?

Comment: @maij I added pastebin to full code and error output.

Comment: when you do something like `playGame().startPlayer` then you first execute `playGame()` and then it gets result from this function and do `result.startPlayer` - probably it is not what you expect. It doesn't give you access to `startPlayer` which you create inside function `playGame()` - it is not class. Problem is that this way you run `playGame()` again and again and again - and you have problem with recursion.

Comment: you have the same problem with `bettingRoundHuman().action`, `bettingRound().won`, and many others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the lines 156-162 and 178-180 of your code from http://pastebin.com/sdfwWjsg:

```
156 def playGame():
157         startPlayer = bettingRoundOrder()
158         human.money = human.money - Table.entrymoney
159         ai.money = ai.money - Table.entrymoney
160         Table.pot = (Table.pot + 2*Table.entrymoney)
161 
162         if bettingRound() == False:


178 def bettingRound():
179         won = False
180         if playGame().startPlayer == 1:
```

These snippets contain the lines 180 and 162 which are mentioned repeatedly in the error message. Now let's see what happens when the `playGame()` function on line 156 gets called: lines 157 - 160 set some variables, line 162 calls `bettingRound()`. Now we are on line 178, line 179 sets a variable, and line 180 calls `playGame()`, so we are back on 156, and this is the infinite loop.

I did not investigate the rest of your code, so I cannot fix the error.

Another remark: If you want to do something like `playGame().startPlayer`, then the `playGame()` function must return an object which has a `startPlayer` member. Neither `Table.winner` (it is a string or None) nor the result of `cardCompare()` (it is a string) will work. Having a `startPlayer` variable somewhere in the `playGame` function is not enough.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for this. I moved the startPlayer variable to the Table class so it doesn't get stuck in loop and it works great now (also makes more sense that way). I do apologies that the question wasn't asked well also.